# How do you avoid values to duplicated?

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, ampscript, dynamic

I'm looking into a DE of past customers transaction, all transactions that contain samples are retargeted with their parent product. In my an email, I'm trying to display up to 4-3 parent products base on their transactional samples child.

I don't fully understand how to hide and stop the AMPscript to create a duplicated data from the DE when the loop passed empty/blank rows value?

For example:

- A customer has 1 transactional samples - It means in the email should display only 1 out 4 displayed products and the other 4 should be hidden since it's an empty/blank value. Right now the value is duplicated in `%%=v=%%` variable syntax.

The methodology is almost similar to an Abandoned Cart campaign.

My code

```
%%[
 var @rowCount, @row, @i, @lookup, @memid, @numRowsToReturn, @RankSample 

 set @memid = AttributeValue("EmailAddress")


 set @numRowsToReturn = 0 /* 0 means all, max 2000 */
 set @lookup = LookupOrderedRows("DE",@numRowsToReturn, "RankSample", "EmailAddress", @memid)

 set @rowCount = rowcount(@lookup)

 if @rowCount > 0 then

 set @RankSample = "12"

 for @i = 1 to @rowCount do

  var @Psample, @Pimage, @Purl, @Pname


  set @row = row(@lookup,@i) /* get row based on counter */
  set @Psample = Field(@row,"SampleProductName")  
  set @Pname = Field(@row,"RecommendProductName")
  set @Purl = Field(@row,"RecommendProductURL")
  set @Pdesc = Field(@row,"RecommendProductDesc")
  set @Pimage = Field(@row,"RecommendImageURL")
  set @Psample = iif(empty(@Psample),"",concat(", ", @Psample)) 
  set @Pname = iif(empty(@Pname),"",concat(", ", @Pname))
  set @Purl = iif(empty(@Purl),"",concat(", ", @Purl)))
  set @Pdesc = iif(empty(@Pdesc),"",concat(", ", @Pdesc))
  set @Pimage = iif(empty(@Pimage),"",concat(", ", @Pimage))



]%%



<table>
    <tr>
      <td>%%=v(@Pname)=%%</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>

      <td><a href="%%=v(@Purl)=%%"><img src="%%=v(@Pimage)=%%" style="display: block"></a></td> 
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>desc:%%=v(@Pdesc)=%%</td>

    </tr>
</table>
<table>
    <tr>  
      <td>%%=v(@Pname)=%%</td>     
    </tr>
    <tr>     
      <td><a href="%%=v(@Purl)=%%"><img src="%%=v(@Pimage)=%%" style="display: block"></a></td>     
    </tr>
    <tr>

      <td>desc:%%=v(@Pdesc)=%%</td>

    </tr>
</table>
<table>
    <tr>  
      <td>%%=v(@Pname)=%%</td>    
    </tr>
    <tr>    
      <td><a href="%%=v(@Purl)=%%"><img src="%%=v(@Pimage)=%%" style="display: block"></a></td>    
    </tr>
    <tr>    
      <td>desc:%%=v(@Pdesc)=%%</td>     
    </tr>
</table>


%%[ next @i ]%%

%%[ else ]%%

<br>No rows found

%%[ endif ]%%
```

*if the topic has been already asked. Let me know, so I can go ready the potential solution. (Sorry for duplicating the question)

Answer (score 0):

Use an if block in the ampscript. if "Psample" is not empty then create the html other wise dont.

Add an if block before your table element.

```
set @Pimage = iif(empty(@Pimage),"",concat(", ", @Pimage))
if not empty(@Psample) then]%%
<table>.....</table>
%%[endif
next @i ]%%
```

Comment: thanks @Praveen for your answer, but it didn't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it's the proper way to do it. I created only one table which will be %%=v=%% more than once based the customer DE. If the customer has 2 or more this will print basically all his transaction activities.

```
%%[
 var @rowCount, @row, @i, @lookup, @memid, @numRowsToReturn, @RankSample 

 set @memid = AttributeValue("EmailAddress")


 set @numRowsToReturn = 0 /* 0 means all, max 2000 */
 set @lookup = LookupOrderedRows("A1_LastPurchasedProducts_Xref",@numRowsToReturn, "RankSample desc", "EmailAddress", @memid)

 set @rowCount = rowcount(@lookup)

 if @rowCount > 0 then

 set @RankSample = "12"

 for @i = 1 to @rowCount do

  var @Psample, @Pimage, @Purl, @Pname


  set @row = row(@lookup,@i) /* get row based on counter */
  set @Psample = Field(@row,"SampleProductName")  
  set @Pname = Field(@row,"RecommendProductName")
  set @Purl = Field(@row,"RecommendProductURL")
  set @Pdesc = Field(@row,"RecommendProductDesc")
  set @Pimage = Field(@row,"RecommendImageURL") 
  ]%%

<table>
   <tr>
      <td>%%=v(@Psample)=%%</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>%%=v(@Pname)=%%</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>    
      <td><a href="%%=v(@Purl)=%%"><img src="%%=v(@Pimage)=%%" style="display: block"></a></td> 
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>desc:%%=v(@Pdesc)=%%</td>  
    </tr>
</table>

%%[ next @i ]%%

%%[ else ]%%

<br>No rows found

%%[ endif ]%%
```

It's not a complete solution. However, It does the trick.